# Log in with Friend, from the server side?

Tags: authentication, clojure, compojure

I'm adding [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend/) to my Compojure app for authentication.  I'm using `workflows/interactive-form`.  I have a form that lets me register a new user (JS POST to `/register`), and I have a form that lets me log in (JS POST to `/login`), and they both work great so far.

I want new user registration to also log in the user, naturally.  Is there an easy way to say "this user is now logged-in" on the server side?

(The client side AJAX call to `/register` has the username and password, so I could simply have it re-encode the form data in the way that `/login` expects, and submit a second AJAX request for the log in.  That seems awkward, though.)

I think that this might have something to do with `:workflows` but that part of the documentation is a bit puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with the same problem also preferring to avoid a second unnecessary AJAX request.  The Friend code is a bit daunting, but you'll want to focus on the `cemerick.friend.workflows/make-auth` and `cemerick.friend/merge-authentication` functions.  It is a complex issue that depends very much on your code, but here is a rough code snippet to get you started in the right direction:

```
(ns my-auth
  (:require [cemerick.friend :as friend]
            [cemerick.friend.workflows :refer [make-auth]]))

(let [user (get-user-data-from-db)
      auth (cemerick.friend.workflows/make-auth user
              {::friend/redirect-on-auth? false})
      merged-auth-in-session (friend/merge-authentication {} auth)])
```

The `make-auth` function gets you the auth structure you need, and the `merge-authentication` function updates the auth in the session.  How you deal with the resulting response (`merged-auth-in-session`) depends on your framework (e.g. Liberator).

Comment: Sir, I do not understand why this was not ever upvoted before. This just got me out of a three-day struggle with Friend docs, and I do not know how to thank you enough.

Comment: Also, if anyone wonders how to return a redirect with session from `merged-auth-in-session` in a typical (I think) Ring app, I did it like this: `(assoc (redirect "/") :session (:session merged-auth-in-session))`